# How to reuse frames in a 2D animation?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites

This is my sprite sheet, when I select the frames and drag them into the scene view to create the animation, it just creates an animation with the selected frames in sequence and I can't figure out how to change that sequence.
If we numbered the frames from left to right and top to botom, I'd need the sequence to be: 2-3-5-2-4-6- and loop.

I can just repeat the frames in the intended sequence, but there must be a smarter way to do this.

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic question, there are lots of tutorials explaining this. I recommend you to watch them first. You would save your time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Animation Panel (Window > Animation). Your animation frames are there. From there you can simply drag one frame to another position in animation to change its place. You can also add other frames, or copy some.